# Plot multiple routes using osmnx

Tags: folium, osmnx

I'm trying to plot multiple routes but error is popping up -
*networkx.exception.NetworkXError: Node [20461931, 75901933] in sequence nbunch is not a valid node.*

Plotting individual route is no more problem but error is raised when plotted together.

```
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox


# Create Graph 
G = ox.graph_from_place('Munich, Germany', network_type='drive')


# route1 calc
origin_node = 20461931
destination_node =   75901933
route1 = nx.shortest_path(G, origin_node, destination_node)

# route2 calc
start =   (48.1336081,  11.58172095)
end = (48.17822992, 11.53754219)
start_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, start)
end_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, end)
route2 = nx.shortest_path(G, start_node, end_node, weight='travel_time')

#plot the route with folium
route_list = [route1,route2]
route_map = ox.plot_route_folium(G,route_list)

# save as html file then display map as an iframe
filepath = 'route.html'
route_map.save(filepath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing it a *list of lists* of nodes, rather than a list of nodes. See the [docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.folium.plot_route_folium) for usage details.

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

G = ox.graph_from_place('Munich, Germany', network_type='drive')
route1 = ox.shortest_path(G, 20461931, 75901933, weight=None)

orig = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (48.1336081,  11.58172095))
dest = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (48.17822992, 11.53754219))
route2 = ox.shortest_path(G, orig, dest, weight='travel_time')

route_map = ox.plot_route_folium(G, route1, route_color='#ff0000', opacity=0.5)
route_map = ox.plot_route_folium(G, route2, route_map=route_map, route_color='#0000ff', opacity=0.5)
route_map.save('route.html')
```

Comment: Note : `get_nearest_node` depricated. Instead use `osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes`. See https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html?highlight=nearest_node#osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes